# Select All object values to list from dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a DTO like this:

```
public class OrderDraft
{
    public string FTPUser             { get; set; }
    public string AccountRef          { get; set; }
    public string SupplyFromWarehouse { get; set; }
    public string UsePriceband        { get; set; }

    public string DocumentDate        { get; set; }
    public string DateRequested       { get; set; }
    public string DatePromised        { get; set; }
    public string CustomerDocumentNo  { get; set; }

    public List<Line> Lines           { get; set; }

    public Address DeliveryAddress    { get; set; }
    public string ShippingChargeCode  { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingFee        { get; set; }
}
```

I create a dictionary of the above like this:

```
Dictionary<string, OrderDraft> multiOrders 
    = new Dictionary<string, OrderDraft>();
```

Now I want to return a `List<OrderDraft>` from the above `multiOrders` dictionary. To achieve this, I tried the following:

- `return multiOrders.SelectMany(s => s.Value);`
- `return multiOrders.SelectMany(s => s.Value).ToList<OrderDraft>;`

I am getting the following error:

> Error 2   The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Any idea how to retrieve a `List<T>` of all values from a `Dictionary<String, T>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
multiOrders.Values.ToList()
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Now I feel stupid. Thanks :) I can accept this answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: I also needed to add `using System.Linq;` to get this to work. :)

Answer (score 0):

@nvoigt solution is dead on, but you could also just deal with the warning by declaring type parameters explicitly:

`return multiOrders.SelectMany<OrderDraft,OrderDraft>(s => s.Value).ToList<OrderDraft>;`